# Pass Series of colors/markers to matplotlib with geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

I am doing some basic mapping with geopandas. I have a geo data frame with a geontry series that are shapely points. The mapping works fine, but what I cannot get get to work is two things:

1. Pass a series to in order to define maker colors. I tried:

   ```
    colors = pd.Series(['r' if val==cond else 'b' for val in gdf], index = gdf.index]) 
    gdf.plot( marker="*" markersize=6, cmap = 'cool', c=colors)
   ```
2. Pass a series to marker in order to define markers. I tried a similar method buy I am getting ValueErrors.

The full code for the marker fail is as follows:

```
#plot the data
gdf.plot(column = 'colors', marker=marker, markersize=6, cmap = 'cool')
plt.xlim([-130, -65])
plt.ylim([20, 52])
plt.title("Map of Walmart Stores (Contiguous States)", size = 15)
plt.xlabel("Latitude")
plt.ylabel("Longitude")
plt.figtext(0.80, 0.2, "Stores = 5212", size = 15)
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: You are passing 'colors' column to 'column' argument. Can you tell us what is behind this 'colors' column. We haven't seen the gdf itself. PS: The colors Series so far has nothing to do with the 'colors' string argument that you are using in gdf...

Comment: Sorry, that is confusing. There is a column in the the gdf called colors that is a series of 1 and 0s. It is really just a dummy variable that represents the outcome of interest. There is also a a series called colors that contains strings representing colors.